# Como fazer uma consulta randômica no MySQL sem repetir dados?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, random, offset

Estou criando um site tipo de imagens tipo Pinterest que, além de outras coisas, precisar combinar as seguintes funcionalidades:

1. Scrool infinito (estou aplicando esse código aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D-CPBvqQaU).
2. Um menu pra escolher em qual ordem exibir as imagens.

O problema acontece quando eu escolho pra exibir as imagens randomicamente: elas se repetem.

A query que estou usando é a seguinte:

```
$return = $database->query("

    SELECT 
        lk_post_pic.*, 
        tb_post.head, 
        tb_post.created_datetime, 
        tb_pic.album, 
        tb_pic.file, 
        tb_pic.thumbnail

    FROM lk_post_pic
    JOIN tb_post ON lk_post_pic.fk_post = tb_post.id_post
    JOIN tb_pic  ON lk_post_pic.fk_pic  = tb_pic.id_pic

    WHERE tb_pic.thumbnail = 'default'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 20
    OFFSET $offset

")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Cada vez que o scroll é rolado até o fundo, essa query é novamente executada e os dados do $return são inseridos num tamplate html, através do echo, que é recebido pela função do jQuery como um response ao GET e, em seguida, é executado o método append().

OBS: Espero não estar complicando com essa divagações, é só pra contextualizar, talvez possa ajudar.

Então, mas a cada vez que essa query é executada, o $offset é acrescido em 20 unidades, pra printar as imagens novas, mas, como tudo é randomizado antes, as imagens do primeiro offset acabam se misturando com a do segundo e daí a exibições são repetidas.

Como contornar problema?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma solução simples seria fazer o ORDER BY RAND na tabela inteira antes de começar a paginação, armazenando somente os IDs da imagem. É um trabalho a mais, mas armazenando somente os IDs na primeira "passada".

Tendo a lista de IDs num array, você usa assim nas páginas:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE id IN ( lista ) ORDER BY RAND();
```

Sendo que `lista` é um subset dos IDs de inicio da pagina ao fim da página (de `$id[iniciodapagina]` até `$id[fimdapagina]`).

### Alternativa matemática

Você pode trocar o lugar do rand para um prévio, antes da paginação, e usar assim

```
ORDER BY MOD(id * $valor, $quantidade_registros + 1) ;
```

Sendo que `$valor` deve ser um **número primo** maior do que a `$quantidade_registros`

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ede03/1)**.

Isto dá certo, pois sendo um número primo, nunca será múltiplo da quantidade, e sempre passará por todos os IDs se pegar a quantidade total de registros.

Como números inteiros geralmente ocupam pouco espaço num DB, você pode pegar uma tabela com uma boa quantidade de primos aqui:

> https://www.bigprimes.net/archive/prime/

Ocupando 13kbytes de espaço você consegue armazenar os primeiros 6500 números primos, que cabem em 2 bytes cada, dando uma bela faixa para usar na *query* acima.

Comment: Gostei muito da segunda alternativa! É bem simplificada mesmo! Mas tem um problema: O código que você escreveu sempre rankeia em primeiro lugar o ultimo item da lista. Pra qualquer valor primo que eu escolha pra $valor, a primeira linha sempre será igual a 69. Como corrigir isso?

Outra coisa: Como faço pra importar essa lista numeros primos pro MySQL?

Comment: Sobre a importação dos primos, ou vc pode fazer uma tabela de primos e sortear um, ou pode simplesmente usar os primos no código PHP, ai fica meio dificil dizer qual é a maneira correta

Comment: Atualizei, o valor do módulo é quantidade + 1, e não quantidade.

Comment: Interessante! Mas, me tira uma outra dúvida a respeito do seguinte: "Sendo que $valor deve ser um número primo maior do que a $quantidade_registros"

E se, após aplicado alguns filtros na tabela em questão, a quantidade de registros for diferente MAX(id_post)?

A princípio, MAX(id_post) = quantidade total de registros, mas depois de aplicar alguns joins e aluns wheres, eu posso ter uma tabela com 500 registros e MAX(id_post) igual a apenas 50. Ou ainda, o MAX(id_post) = 200 e quantidade total de registros = 16.

Nessa situação, como interpretar e aplicar corretamente a sua fórmula?

Comment: Se vc pegar os primeiros cerca de 6500 primos, terá números até 65000 + -, basta sortear do primeiro maior que o count(*) até o ultimo

Comment: Perceba que a 2a solução vale a pena pra quantidades muito grandes de imagens, se for pra fazer uma paginação com 5 selects, provavelmente a idéia dos primos não justifica.

Comment: É importante que a quantidade de registros seja igual ao numero de linhas da tabela que eu estou consultado? Minhas queries são super complicadas, envolvem até subqueries, fazer essa conta como parâmetro e depois fazer ela de novo na sub e denovo na principal vai consurmir bastante recurso do servidor...

Comment: JHenry vi que aceitou minha resposta, sugiro uma boa olhada na solução do colega @Pagotti, talvez no seu caso seja mais simples de implementar. Se funcionar bem para o seu caso, é até mais leve para o servidor. (mas use um valor maior de rand(), 1000 é pouco. veja meu comentário na postagem dele).

Answer (score 2):

### Use um valor fixo como parâmetro para o `RAND()`

Uma forma de fazer paginação e manter a ordem aleatória usando o [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) é passar um número fixo como parâmetro porque dessa forma a ordem será a mesma em todas as chamadas e vai se manter na paginação. E para gerar a aleatoriedade que você precisa, você faz o sorteio desse número que vai passar quando o usuário carregar a primeira página.

Para controlar isso, uma forma é guardar na sessão do usuário esse valor. Se o seu sistema não usa sessões, talvez você tenha que achar algum mecanismo como retornar o número gerado junto com o retorna da primeira página, guardar ele no lado do browser e quando pedir a próxima página passar esse número... Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, escolha uma que sirva melhor para o seu caso.

Usando a sessão, ficaria algo como:

```
session_start();
if ($offset == 0) {
   $seed = rand(1, 1000);
   $_SESSION["seed"] = $seed;
} else {
   $seed = $_SESSION["seed"];
}

$return = $database->query("

    SELECT 
        lk_post_pic.*, 
        tb_post.head, 
        tb_post.created_datetime, 
        tb_pic.album, 
        tb_pic.file, 
        tb_pic.thumbnail

    FROM lk_post_pic
    JOIN tb_post ON lk_post_pic.fk_post = tb_post.id_post
    JOIN tb_pic  ON lk_post_pic.fk_pic  = tb_pic.id_pic

    WHERE tb_pic.thumbnail = 'default'
    ORDER BY RAND($seed)
    LIMIT 20
    OFFSET $offset

")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Parece bom, só tem que tomar cuidado se ele fizer alguma otimização meio maluca em alguma query (o manual faz uma observação nesse sentido). Pra queries simples o seed fixo é uma boa, e provavelmente é a maneira mais simples de implementar.

Comment: Só uma sugestão, seria lega um `$seed = rand();` sem especificar a faixa, pois aí o PHP já usa automaticamente a maior faixa possível.

Comment: Concordo contigo. Sempre tem que observar as limitações e fazer vários testes antes de usar uma solução.

Comment: Espero que o autor experimente a sua, tenho uma forte impressão que é mais adequada pro cenário dele, [como eu já havia comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327160/como-fazer-uma-consulta-rand%c3%b4mica-no-mysql-sem-repetir-dados/327163#comment663286_327163).